# How to find specific url from list of urls - python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I a working with urls. I have a list of urls which I am getting from a scraping activity. However, I need to select one url which contains "decision-makers".

### Code:

```
src = driver.page_source
 
# Now using beautiful soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(a['href'])
```

Output from the code:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/?
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/?decidion-makers
https://www.linkedin.com/messaging/?
https://www.linkedin.com/notifications/?
/company/infosys/
```

Expected output:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/?decidion-makers
```

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = soup.select_one("a[href*=decision-makers]")
dm = a['href']
print(dm)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas and regex module if you want :

```
import pandas as pd
import re

urls = ["https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/?",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/?decidion-makers",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/messaging/?",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/notifications/?",
        "/company/infosys/"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=urls)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = row[0]

    match = re.search(r"(.*decidion-makers)", url)
    if match:
        print(url)
```

Output :

```
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/?decidion-makers
```